# Switching required input fields validate dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 2 buttons (**Save Draft** and **Save Final FORM**).
I would like to switch the required fields depending on which button pressed.
When I push the **Save Draft** it's required to fill out only the **Name's** field.
When I push the **Save Final FORM** it's required to fill all of the fields except **Text** field.
How can I do that?

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>FORM</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Test From</h2>
        <br>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post">
        <h5>Types</h5>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                          <input type="radio" id="type_s" name="types" value="S" class="custom-control-input">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="type_s">Type (S)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                          <input type="radio" id="type_z" name="types" value="Z" class="custom-control-input">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="type_z">Type (Z)</label>
                        </div>                      
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                          <input type="radio" id="type_r" name="types" value="R" class="custom-control-input">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="type_r">Type (R)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                          <input type="radio" id="type_t" name="types" value="T" class="custom-control-input">
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="type_t">Type (T)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>               
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control float-right" id="Number" name="Number"  oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Number" >
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Number</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control float-right" id="Number2" name="Number2"  oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="5" placeholder="Number2" >
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Number2</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control float-right" id="Text" name="Text" placeholder="Text" maxlength="15" >
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Text</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        <h5>Name</h5>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required >
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Name</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h6>Select:</h6>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <select class="custom-select" id="select" name="select" >
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
                        <option value="select_1">Select 1</option>
                        <option value="select_1">Select 2</option>
                        <option value="select_1">Select 3</option>
                        <option value="select_1">Select 4</option>
                    </select>
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Please Select</small>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="no-print text-center">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="form_draft" value="Save Draft">    
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="form_new" value="Save Final FORM">
            </div>            
    </form>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks ;)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nzlorca/ge0n1d9p/)

Comment: What have you tried prior to asking the question? You should be able to show us what attempts you've made and from there we could help you out. That being said, there are a couple ways you can do this. First is to manually verify the fields you need to on each button click. If there are missing fields, you can then return false and the form will not submit. Or you can use a plugin like [jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) where you can set specifically required fields depending on other variables.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new in Javascript. I only know that this can be solved with javascript. I tried to find that solution, but I find only that it can be work in 2 separate forms. I don't want that.

Comment: Check my answer below for an idea on how to go forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `click eventlistener` to your buttons.

Add this at the END of your file before closing `</body>` tag. I've only given you an example of the first button. You should be able to reproduce this however you want for the other button.

```
<script>
    var btnformdraft = document.getElementsByName("form_draft")[0];
    btnformdraft.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        //set default doContinue
        let doContinue = true;

        //verify your fields here
        if(document.getElementById("Name").value === "") {
            doContinue = false;
        }
        
        //add other field verifications

        //verify if we continue 
        if(!doContinue) {
            evt.preventDefault();
          //showing alert BUT THIS CAN BE CHANGED TO HOWEVER YOU WANT TO DISPLAY THE ERROR MESSAGE
          alert('The NAME field is required');
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: It is seems to work thanks ;) 
I would like html required instead of js alert message. So how can I put the required to the necessary input fields?

Comment: You can APPEND a `<span>` after the element in question and put the error message in the span. - Upvote/Mark the answer as accepted if you are happy with the results. Thanks

Comment: I understand, but I want to add only the required attribute to the input filed like that:
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>

Comment: Ok, I added this:
document.getElementById("Number").required = true;
Thanx your HELP ;)